# Facebook Open Graph Action + Rails: return JSON or HTML

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I've implemented Facebook's Open Graph per Ryan Bates' awesome tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/363-facebook-open-graph

However, when Facebook is scraping my site to retrieve the `og` parameters, it looks like it's asking for JSON format. That's a problem since I'm already using JSON to return data for other purposes. I'm ok returning data for Facebook via `format.html`. I checked the request object and I see this ACCEPT header:

```
'HTTP_ACCEPT' */*
```

However, that's causing my app to execute `format.json`. I played around with the order of the format responses and it still requests `format.json`.

```
respond_with(@project) do |format|
    format.html { render 'show'}
    format.json { render 'show'}
    format.js { render 'show'}
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured out that with an Accept Header of `*/*`, and if you are using `respond_with`, you'll need to make sure the `respond_to` at the top of the controller matches the order you want... In my case, this is correct:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  respond_to :json
  respond_to :js,
  ...
```

and this isn't

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  respond_to :html
  respond_to :js,
  ...
```

Comment: Great! This saved me some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

A note, you may also have to change the order:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @this.to_json }
  format.html
end
```

to:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @this.to_json }
end
```

as saying in [facebook open graph crawler triggering json response in rails actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112467/facebook-open-graph-crawler-triggering-json-response-in-rails-actions)