# Facebook crawler seems to trigger Forbidden errors on my ExpressJS app

Tags: facebook, node.js, express

I've noticed that everytime I use the [Facebook debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) or the Facebook like button (set up using [Addthis](http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins/facebook-like-button)) ExpressJS ends up throwing `Error: Forbidden` (twice in a row).

So I assume the crawler sends a request that weirds out Express, maybe something in the headers like for this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112467/facebook-open-graph-crawler-triggering-json-response-in-rails-actions)?

Here is the header sent by Facebook crawler:

```
{ 
    host: 'runningheroes.co',
    accept: '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'deflate, gzip',
    range: 'bytes=0-8999',
    referer: 'http://runningheroes.co/',
    'user-agent': 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)',
    'x-forwarded-for': '173.252.100.117',
    'x-forwarded-port': '80',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
    connection: 'keep-alive' 
}
```

And here is my Express config:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
    app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'secret', cookie: { domain: '.runningheroes.co', maxAge: 1000*60*60*24, httpOnly: true } }));

    app.use(app.router);

    // Error handling:
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        if(!err) { return next(); }
        // This is were the Forbidden errors are logged
        logger.error('Express.error.middleware: ' + err);
        res.redirect('/error');
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

PS: the debugger still succeed to parse the og meta tags and the like button works as well despite the errors.

Comment: Related, might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112467/facebook-open-graph-crawler-triggering-json-response-in-rails-actions (it might be the accepts header `*/*` that messes up Express)

Comment: yeah could be the reason, no idea how to fix it though...