# Rails app : Link sharer of Facebook request JSON instead of HTML in my

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, facebook

I've got a Facebook sharer with this code :

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436');return false;">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</a>
```

But Facebook get the content of the "json" result instead of the html result !

How can i solve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook open graph crawler triggering json response in rails actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112467/facebook-open-graph-crawler-triggering-json-response-in-rails-actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the order of format you defined in controller. For example, here are some cases Facebook would get JSON instead of HTML

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
   respond_with :json, :html
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
      respond_with(@posts)
   end
end
```

or

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
   respond_with :json, :html
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json{ render json: @posts }
         format.html
      end
   end
end
```

In both cases, you just need to move :html option to be the first option and everything will be all right.

Note: You would need to force FB to fetch your page again in order to see the result because FB caches page result.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Do you know how to force FB to fetch again the result ?

Comment: @p0k3 https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. Just type in your URL and then you would see the option to force FB to re-fetch the result